# Bash: How use while loop while receiving input from program?

Tags: bash, while-loop, readline

I'm trying to back up songs before an impending harddrive crash. Hurry!

I saved the output of ls to a file. Then I tried to read said file for the names of the files I'm trying to back up. The problem with most bands and artists is they use more than one word (eg "Kings of Leon"). Anyway reading it in it thinks I want directories "Kings", "of", "Leon". In frustration I wrote this script, pc is a c program that reads in the names of the files from a file on my desktop, because I thought I might not be able to read in the names the normal way. Now I need to know how to use a while loop to read in the names being output from "pc" before program returns 0.

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
i="nonsense"
while i=$(./pc)
    cp -r "\"/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1/Users/mac/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/$(echo $i)\"" "\"iTunes/$(echo $i)\""
done
exit 0
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read i; do
    cp "/Volumes/Macintosh HD 1/Users/mac/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/$i" "iTunes/$i"
done < <(./pc)
exit 0
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Now I have other problems but this one is solved. Thanks again.